# Users cannot send files to Microsoft Teams chatbot

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a Mirosoft Teams app/chatbot installed with the personal and team scopes as a tenant app in a customer's tenant.

We have received a report from a user that they cannot send files to the bot, as the paperclip icon is not available in the chat with the bot.

Note that the bot's `supportsFiles` is set to `true` in the manifest.

Could this be due to a scope mismatch, e.g. app used personally instead of as a team app? Why would the behavior change?

Comment: Are you using Graph API or Teams API to send file? Please take a look at [send and receive files through bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files).

Comment: Hi, I use Teams API, and the issue is not with the *bot* sending files but with the *user* sending files. The documentation is not helpful on this because in my case, the paperclip icon, which allows a user to send the bot a file, is completely deactivated (but specifically with our bot)

Comment: Could you please share you manifest?